# Do foreach in tr table Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table html. I want to get all columns names. I was trying but nothing.

> ```
> $('#tblmodelos th').each(function () {
>     var $data = $(this).html();
>     console.log($data);
> });
> ```

Comment: ...and then what happened?

Comment: Make sure that table has `id="tblmodelos"` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the `name` attribute...

Try this:

```
$('#tblmodelos th').each(function () {
    var $data = $(this).attr("name");
    alert($data);
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0pnbxpy2/)**

`.html()` will give you the value between `<th>` and `</th>`

For example, if you have:

```
<th>Testing</th>
```

It will return `Testing`.

**UPDATE**

Use `document.ready` function so everything will execute as soon as the DOM is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tblmodelos th').each(function () {
    var $data = $(this).text();
    console.log($data);
});
});
```

Comment: Don't think so. `th` elements can't have `name` attribute.

Comment: @Oriol explained further what `.html()` will output... I guess the question isn't quite clear.

Comment: by ``name`` OP means the text inside ``th``. - meaning the "name" of the column. i hope so :)

Comment: It is clear, `th` are for table headers and in most cases they will contain the column name.

Comment: and well the OP JS works anyway :)

Comment: @doniyor Updated it... I guess you all are right!

Comment: @imbondbaby dont use ``html()`` to get the string name, it could give more than that. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could it just be the good old `$(document).ready(function() {});` trap?

```
$(function() {  // same as document.ready
  $('#tblmodelos th').each(function () {
    var $data = $(this).html();
    console.log($data);
  });
});
```

As your code works fine then as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/o6a2vwg0/

Otherwise I see no reason why this code would fail if the HTML is correct

Answer (score 0):

if you mean by `name` the column name, then try this

```
$(function () {
  $('#tblmodelos th').each(function () {
    var thname = $(this).text();        
  });
});
```

**working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/doniyor/45xhw94h/

in this case, you should use `text()` rather than `html()`, because `html()` would retrieve with everything inside `th` if you have something like this:

```
<th>
  <span>The column name</span> 
</th>
```

output with `html()` would be:

```
<span>The column name</span>
```